# Can A .net combobox point directly to an object?

Tags: vb.net, list, object, combobox

This should be a quick one.

I am wondering if a .net combobox can point to an instance of an object.

Currently I am populating the combobox with this:

```
Private Sub validation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        paramPairComboBox.ValueMember = "uniqueName"
        paramPairComboBox.DisplayMember = "name"
        paramPairComboBox.DataSource = payload.parameterPairs

End Sub ''validation_Load()
```

As you can see, I have to use a string that is unique to a specific object as the ValueMember.

What's really bugging me is the fact that I have to do this:

```
Private Sub paramPairComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles paramPairComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim graphBuilder As GraphBuilder
        Dim indexSearch As IndexFinder = New IndexFinder(paramPairComboBox.SelectedValue)
        Dim pairIndex As Integer = payload.parameterPairs.FindIndex(AddressOf indexSearch.find)
        indexSearch = Nothing
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(pairIndex)

        Dim param1 As String = payload.parameterPairs(pairIndex).param1
        Dim param2 As String = payload.parameterPairs(pairIndex).param2

        graphBuilder = New GraphBuilder(payload.testData.table, payload.parameterPairs(pairIndex))

        engineChart.Series.Clear()

        engineChart.Series.Add(graphBuilder.getSeries())
        engineChart.ResetAutoValues()
    End Sub ''paramPairComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
End Class

''' <summary>
''' Class to provide search functionality
''' </summary>
Class IndexFinder

    Dim _s As String

    Public Sub New(s As String)
        _s = s
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The search function
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pair"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function find(pair As LimitParameterPair) As Boolean
        Return pair.uniqueName.Contains(_s)
    End Function ''find()

End Class
```

To sum up that code, I have to create a class thaat facilitates searching for that unique string inside of a list of objects. It seems cumbersome to me.

So basically, is there any way to accomplish something like this:

```
Private Sub validation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        paramPairComboBox.ValueMember = Me (or) This (or something??)
        paramPairComboBox.DisplayMember = "name"
        paramPairComboBox.DataSource = payload.parameterPairs

    End Sub ''validation_Load()
```

Comment: what kind of object is `payload` seems like a fairly involved way to find the related item

Comment: I'm truly sorry but I can't make heads or tails of what you said...

Comment: you use `payload.parameterPairs` as the DataSource - what is it?  DataTable, List, something else?

Comment: Oh sorry, It's a list. A list of some arbitrary objects.

Comment: `IndexFinder ` could be replaced by a simple linq query to get the selected one.  `thisOne = payload.parameterPairs.FirstOrDefault(Function (f) f.name=paramPairComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString)` then just pass that to `GraphBuilder()`; then remove param1/2 which arent used and it is a lot shorter/simpler

Comment: Thanks for the help, and while your suggestion seems viable, my answer below is the simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer was right under my nose. By default, the combobox will point to the selected object not via `SelectedValue` but rather `SelectedItem`

So, my code becomes:

```
Private Sub validation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        paramPairComboBox.DataSource = payload.parameterPairs
        paramPairComboBox.DisplayMember = "name"

    End Sub ''validation_Load()
```

I can then reference the instance of the object simply by using `paramPairComboBox.SelectedItem`

Comment: ...that too :)  I didnt notice that